# Linked list containing char Pep/8

Tags: assembly, pep8-assembly

Good morning,

I am trying to make a linked list which must contain a char for each node. So first the teacher provided us a code. 
This code creates a linked list where we can put numbers. Then we must change the code to output the numbers in order of size (0 to 99999). This was easily done. For example i can type:

`"3 5 4 2 1"` and my list will contain:

```
[3|adr_nxt] [5|adr_nxt] [4|adr_nxt] [2|adr_nxt] [1|adr_nxt]
```

and then it will output: 12345

Next step is to replace numbers with char.

For example i type: `"hdbcu"` and the list will contain each char separately :

```
[h|adr_nxt] [d|adr_nxt] [b|adr_nxt] [c|adr_nxt] [u|adr_nxt]
```

then it should output : bcdhu

So what i did was change the size of the value in the list from 2 bytes to 1 as it is advised by the teacher.

My problem is that it works if i let it 2 bytes and do a `CHARI mVal,x` 
but if i do (after putting only 1 byte)

```
CHARI letter,d
LDA 0,i
LDBYTEA letter,d
STA mVal,x
```

then it doesnt work anymore and gives me crap values (and mess up my pointers too)

```
[00|wrong_adress] for every node
```

here is my code: https://pastebin.com/yyHRB89V
it's quite long so i putted it in a pastebin instead.

tl;dr: i must put chars in a linked list and then sort them in alphabetical order. I can't put them in the linked list.

Answer (score 0):

So i did find the answer and it works using `STBYTEA`

So the final code would be :

```
CHARI letter,d
LDA 0,i
LDBYTEA letter,d
STBYTEA mVal,x
```

And it works !